# How does the Omnitrix work?

Tags: ben-10

Recently, I decided to rewatch Ben 10. I became interested in certain aspects of the Omnitrix.

How does the Omnitrix convert a human  (or any other species for that matter ) into another species? I know it has something to do with genetic manipulation but how does the Omnitrix go about doing that? To say it's some form of energy as some have suggested to me seems a little far fetched. Others say it uses some form of virus that infects the user with foreign alien DNA, but that sounds even more far fetched.
Can anyone help? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It uses [magic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkesThirdLaw) and [Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum). I'm not joking- even in-story, its creator doesn't know how it works.

Comment: @yasskier I find that hard to swallow as well the Omnitrix is obviously a form of technology with the holograms, and signals from Primus. I find it harder to believe that Azmuth creator of the Omnitrix Ultimatrix Unitrix and the Omnitrix 2.0, smartest being in three (arguably 4) galaxies has no idea what makes the Omnitrix work. Also gwen tennison even said herself magic isn't really it's really just manipulation of mana

Comment: @user85749 - Whether it’s got a fancy Austronesian or Hebrew name or not doesn’t really change what it is....

Comment: @adaman the wiki isn't very clear but it is definitely not magic. It states that the original Omnitrix "glitches" and that it received "software updates" from Galvan

Comment: Since the creator (man of action) does not know how it works, allow me to speculate.  If we assume that the discontinuity caused by certain episodes can be explained by multiverse theory (gwen 10 existing in it's own personal universe), then it is possible that the omnitrix is an interdimensional teleportation device.  Ben just swaps out with a version of himself from a dimension that corresponds with that universe (so in one universe Ben is a member of the 4-arms alien species).  Please note that this speculation may be utter nonsense, but at least I tried.

Comment: I read it fast and I'm tired, so I thought this question was going to be about my namesake. :P

Comment: well it's extremely unlikely to be a virus, simply because changing a creatures D.N.A. just changes the proteins they produce E.g. if i swapped out all my D.N.A. for that of my cat i wouldn't turn in to a cat, i would just die (within about two hours). it's more likely that it works in a similar vein to the replicator or transporter technology of the star trek universe physically replacing the body cell by cell with the body of the species. the "design" for the body itself is probably produced based on a computer simulation of the aliens D.N.A. similar to a mega evolution.

Comment: I remember there was a thing called Omnienergy which had the capability to destroy the universe..

Comment: I may be late to this discussion but I believe the canonical answer is, "Very well, thank you for asking."

Comment: Haha, one year later and I’m back here because I made the same mistake! :P

Answer (score 2):

Canonically, no one actually knows except for Azmuth. When it comes to the Omnitrix, Azmuth refuses to answer what the processes for anything but collecting DNA from aliens actually are, and since Ben doesn't really care to investigate it and just cares about it working, we'll likely never truly know the how or why of the Omnitrix. *Ben 10* is based off of Ben's perspective, nothing more, nothing less, and as such we don't know anything other than "the Omnitrix turns the user into aliens." That's been my experience, at any rate.